# Does this code leak?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I just ran my app through the Leaks in Instruments and I am being told that the following code causes leaks, but I don't see how.

I allocate some `NSMutableArray`s in my `viewDidLoad` with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.currentCars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.expiredCars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Then I populate these arrays inside of my `viewWillAppear` method with the following:

```
[self.currentCars removeAllObjects];
[self.expiredCars removeAllObjects];
for (Car *car in [self.dealership cars]) {
    if ([car isCurrent])
        [self.currentCars addObject:car];

    if ([car isExpired])
        [self.expiredCars addObject:car];
}
```

And later in the code I release these arrays here:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    if (currentCars != nil) {
        [currentCars release], currentCars = nil;
    }
    if (expiredCars != nil) {
        [expiredCars release], expiredCars = nil;
    }

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not seeing any leaks. Must be elsewhere, could you add some related code?

Comment: It's impossible to tell based solely on that sample.

Comment: Perhaps I'm looking at the wrong place in Instruments, but it hilights the line `[self.currentCars addObject:car];` and puts an indicator with 100% on that line... Am I just reading it wrong?

Comment: @Bill Shiff We need to see how those properties are set and what eventually happens to currentCars and expiredCars to be able to tell. (Are you releasing them in your dealloc?)

Comment: @RyanJM: Arrays always maintain their own pointers, i.e. they retain them the moment objects are added, release the moment objects are removed.

Comment: Posted more code to explain how I create and release the variables

Comment: Are you changing the contents of currentCars and expiredCars anywhere else, or is that it? (And where does dealership enter/exit the picture.)

Comment: @Bill Post the declaration of your properties (currentCars, expiredCars) as well.

Comment: They don't say it very well, but an NSArray releases all of its contents when you release it. Supposedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your leak is here:

```
self.currentCars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.expiredCars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Assuming that you declared property accessores like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *currentCars;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *expiredCars;
```

In my opinion, the best way to find leaks (other than using Instruments) is to keep track of the retain count manually.

If you were to do that with for example `currentCars`, you would find your leak easily. Here is what happens:

```
self.currentCars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// The 'init' makes the retain count 1. 

// 'self.currentCars = ..' translates to the setCurrentCars: method.
// You probably did not implement that method yourself,
// but by synthesizing your property it is automatically implemented like this:
- (void)setCurrentCars:(NSMutableArray *)array {
    [array retain]; // Makes the retain count 2
    [currentCars release]; 
    currentCars = array;
}

// In your viewWillDisappear: method
[currentCars release], currentCars = nil; // Makes the retain count 1 so the object is leaked.
```

The solution is simple. Use this:

```
NSMutableArray *tempMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.currentCars = tempMutableArray;
[tempMutableArray release];
```

A little sidenote. You shouldn't release your objects in `viewWillDisappear:`. The recommended place to do that is `dealloc`. So your code would be:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [currentCars release], currentCars = nil;
    [expiredCars release], expiredCars = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Calls to `-init` don't change retain counts. The retain count is set to 1 (at least as far as we know) by the call to `-alloc`, though Apple advises thinking in terms of ownership rather than retain counts, since trying to calculate retain counts rests on assumptions that will not always prove to be correct.

Comment: Also, it's not necessarily wrong to release objects in `-viewWillDisappear:` to decrease memory consumption as long as the underlying instance variables are set to `nil`, as the OP has done here. On the other hand, setting instance variables to `nil` in `-dealloc` is unlikely to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is (probably) that you are using the property accessors for the initial setting of the  arrays in -viewDidLoad.  Since well-implemented property accessors will retain the object, you are getting 1 retain from the +alloc and another retain from assigning it.  To fix this, you should release your arrays after assigning them or use `[NSMutableArray array]` to get an autoreleased one to use for your initial assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing something very odd in `currentCars`, `expiredCars`, `dealership` or `cars`, no, there's no leak there.

Instruments' pointer to the location of a leak isn't necessarily where the object is actually leaked, per se. If I were to guess, I'd say you're probably neglecting to release either `currentCars` or `expiredCars` in your dealloc method.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering if viewWillDisappear is guaranteed to be called.